# Convert query aggregate mongodb to java @Aggregation

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, hibernate

I have a query in studio3T:

```
db.getCollection("event_management").aggregate([
{$match: {"job_monitor_id": { $in: ["6375e5b4268c0b5d83db13a5"] }}},
{
    $group: {
        _id: "$job_monitor_id",
        success: { $sum: { $cond: [{
             $in: ["$status", ["SUCCESS", "PROCESS", "FAILED_BY_EXECUTING", "EXPIRED"]] 
             }, 1, 0] } },
        fail: { $sum: { $cond: [{ $in: ["$status", ["FAILED_BY_SENDING"]] }, 1, 0] } },
    }
}
])
```

I tried to convert to java hibernate:

```
@Aggregation(pipeline = {
      "{$match:{'job_monitor_id': {$in : ?0}}}",
      "{'$group':{_id: '$job_monitor_id'," +
            "success: {$sum : {$cond :  [{$in :  ['$status', ?1 ]}, 1, 0]}}," +
            "fail:  {$sum : {$cond :  [{$in :  ['$status',  ?2 ]}, 1, 0]}},}}"
})
List<JSONObject> sumRecordEvent(List<String> events, List<String> statusSuccess, List<String> statusFail);
```

I printed the query to the console:

```
db.getCollection("event_management").aggregate([
    { "$match" : { 
                    "job_monitor_id" : { "$in" : ["6375e5b4268c0b5d83db13a5"]}
                 }
    }, 
    { "$group" : { "_id" : "$job_monitor_id", 
                    "success" : { "$sum" : { "$cond" : [{ "$in" : ["$status", "SUCCESS", "PROCESS", "FAILED_BY_EXECUTING", "EXPIRED"]}, 1, 0]}},
                    "fail" : { "$sum" : { "$cond" : [{ "$in" : ["$status", "FAILED_BY_SENDING"]}, 1, 0]}}
                 }
    }
]);
```

I see my mistake `$in` in `$group` but I don't know how to fix it.
Can someone help me. I am very grateful and appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to wrap, the parameters `['$status', ?1 ]`, in square brackets as well, like this `['$status', [?1] ]`. So, the whole query becomes:

```
@Aggregation(pipeline = {
      "{$match:{'job_monitor_id': {$in : ?0}}}",
      "{'$group':{_id: '$job_monitor_id'," +
            "success: {$sum : {$cond :  [{$in :  ['$status', [?1] ]}, 1, 0]}}," +
            "fail:  {$sum : {$cond :  [{$in :  ['$status',  [?2] ]}, 1, 0]}},}}"
})
List<JSONObject> sumRecordEvent(List<String> events, List<String> statusSuccess, List<String> statusFail);
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried again and the results were not correct.